# Xen installion error

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I am newbie to virtualisation and as a first step I tried to install XEN from Ubuntu     12.10 on dual boot mode(another OS is windows 8).
    But for some reason(unknown to me) it is not working,I tried the following command after installation and booting into "xen hypervisor".

From terminal I gave the following command to check if xen is installed prperly or no

```
  $ sudo xm list
    Traceback (most recent call last):                              
      File "/usr/sbin/xm", line 5, in <module>
        from xen.xm import main
    ImportError: No module named xen.xm



I want to know if its Ok to install hypervisor in dual boot mode or I will have to 
reinstall XEN and them install other OS on top of it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 won't install with Xen hypervisor. Xen is not compatible with Windows OS directly. Instead, it is okay that you create a virtual machine and then you are able to install windows os into the VM.

Regards,
Yeonki

Comment: Ya ,now I have set up XEN hypervisor on complete hard-disk using Ubuntu 13.04 its working quite fine  until we don't bother about response time..It took me approx 5 hours to reach the login screen of VM(i.e Ubuntu 11.10).Is there anything I can do to improve the response time(I assigned 3 cpu's and 2 GB of Ram to that VM using "virt-managger").

Answer (score 0):

The Xen kernel must load before the (Ubuntu) kernel. Make sure your grub is set to load the Xen kernel on startup, otherwise it will just boot into Ubuntu with the same kernel and services you always use an you won't get any Xen functionality.

You can either manually edit the grub.cfg or if you are using grub2 do something like:

```
#add grub2 to boot into Xen
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-set-default 'Ubuntu Linux Server, with Xen hypervisor'
```